# iam facing a error to searchbar in reactjs code

Tags: reactjs

Here is my js file

```
       constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          query: "",
          countries: [],
          searchString:[]

        }
      }

      handleInputChange = (event) => {
        this.setState({
            query: event.target.value
        },()=>{
      this.filterArray();
    })

    }
      componentDidMount() {
        const apiUrl = 'https://indian-cities-api-nocbegfhqg.now.sh/cities';
        fetch(apiUrl)
          .then(res => res.json())
          .then(
            (result) => {

              this.setState({
                countries: result,
                searchString:result
              });

            },
            console.log("hello",this.state.countries)
            // (error) => {
            //   this.setState({ error });
            // }
          )
      }
      filterArray = () => {
        let searchString = this.state.query;
        let result = this.state.countries;


        if(searchString.length > 0){
          // console.log(responseData[i].name);
          result = result.filter(searchString);
    this.setState({
      result
    })
      }

    }

      render() {
        const { countries} = this.state;

        console.log("country",this.state)
          return(
            <div>
              <h2>countrie List</h2>
              <form>
                    <input type="text" id="filter" placeholder="Search for..."  onChange={this.handleInputChange}/>
                </form>
              <Table>
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>#ID</th>
                    <th>countrie Name</th>
                    <th>Code</th>
                    <th>States</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  {countries.map(countrie => (
                    <tr key={countrie.City}>
                      <td>{countrie.sno}</td>
                      <td>{countrie.City}</td>
                      <td>{countrie.State}</td>
                      <td>{countrie.District}</td>
                    </tr>
                  ))}

                </tbody>

              </Table>
            </div>
          )
                  }

                }           
          export default TableList;
```

This is my error

```
TypeError: d is not a function
TableList.filterArray
        D:/campstar2.0_cp/src/views/TableList.jsx:132
          129 |     
          130 |     if(searchString.length > 0){
          131 |       // console.log(responseData[i].name);
        > 132 |       result = result.filter(searchString);
          133 | this.setState({
          134 |   result
          135 | })
        View compiled
        TableList.<anonymous>
        D:/campstar2.0_cp/src/views/TableList.jsx:102
           99 |     this.setState({
          100 |         query: event.target.value
          101 |     },()=>{
        > 102 |   this.filterArray();
          103 | })
          104 | 
          105 | }
```

Comment: The error message appears unrelated to the code you are showing

Comment: it showing error as type error  which word iam trying to search ex: if iwant search india it shows i is not a function,like that i search usa it shows u is not afunction

Comment: you have ()=>{this.filterArray(); within the setState. Extract that and move it to outside the setState call. and you don't need ()=>

Comment: i didn't get could u please modify it